# Detecting gamepad input

Tags: c#, gamepad

Code so far:

```
Device gamepad;
public bool initializeGamePad()
        {
            foreach ( DeviceInstance di in Manager.GetDevices(DeviceClass.GameControl, EnumDevicesFlags.AttachedOnly) )
            {
                gamepad = new Device(di.InstanceGuid);
                break;
            }

            if (gamepad==null)//no gamepads detected
                return false;
            else
            {
                configureGamePad();
                return true;
            }
        }

        public void configureGamePad()
        {
            //Set axis ranges
            foreach (DeviceObjectInstance doi in gamepad.Objects)
            {
                if ((doi.ObjectId & (int)DeviceObjectTypeFlags.Axis) != 0)
                {
                    gamepad.Properties.SetRange(ParameterHow.ById, doi.ObjectId, new InputRange(-5000, 5000));
                }
            }

            //Set joystick axis mode absolute
            gamepad.Properties.AxisModeAbsolute = true;

            //set cooperative level.
            gamepad.SetCooperativeLevel(new Form1(), CooperativeLevelFlags.NonExclusive | CooperativeLevelFlags.Background);

            //Acquire devices for capturing
            gamepad.Acquire();

            UpdateJoystick();
        }

        private void UpdateJoystick()
        {
            string info = "Joystick: ";

            //Get Mouse State
            JoystickState state = gamepad.CurrentJoystickState;

            //Capture Position
            info += "X:" + state.X + " ";
            info += "Y:" + state.Y + " ";
            info += "Z:" + state.Z + " ";
            info += "ARx:" + state. + "\n";

            //Capture Buttons
            byte[] buttons = state.GetButtons();
            for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Length; i++)
            {
                if (buttons[i] != 0)
                {
                    info += "Button:" + i + " ";
                }
            }

            MessageBox.Show(info);
        }
```

The problem is that the info string contains only the value 0 for state.X/Y/Z and nothing in regards to buttons.

I need something like this: button_down & button_release in order to get 2 or more simultanious buttons pressed. And the axis pozisions.

Also I only use the DirectX SKD no SlimDX or anyting else.

Comment: Well generally speaking Gamepad input is for games. I've only used gamepads through XNA. Could you specify what type of gamepad you're using? Xbox Controller, flight stick, generic D-Pad/Analog/4Button/Triggers?

Comment: I'm using a wireless genius gamepad
http://s1.emagst.ro/products/24/23618/images/img50860_02092009105416_350x350c_71dt.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably have to interface with DirectX in a managed form. Check out [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929764/taking-input-from-a-joystick-with-c-sharp-net) on SO for more details. But essentially it's just polling for input and then processing your own events. If you have further questions beyond the "how do I get this going" feel free to comment and I'll edit if I can.

Comment: I cant seem to get started with writing 1 line of code. It seems that without XNA nothing works but I dont want to make an XNA project because I'm not making a game. Can you give me a little project in visual studio that can detect gamepad input and create a msg box everytime you press a key?

Comment: What you're asking for is out of order for SO. I've provided an article with sample code and other references. I can't write a project that does it for you.

Comment: I've changed my question