# cant find joystick guid using sharpDX directinput

Tags: c#, sharpdx, joystick, directinput

i'm trying to use a ps3 controller for a game i'm creating. I downloaded the sharpDX.DirectInput extension into my visual studio XNA solution, and used the seemingly simple code from Valdemar's answer in [Taking input from a joystick with C# .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929764/taking-input-from-a-joystick-with-c-sharp-net). I already narrowed the problem down to the fact that he cant find the guid of the controller, nor the guid of other USB connected devices such as a keyboard. It does works for the integrated keyboard of my laptop though. Here is my code:

```
directInput = new DirectInput();
// Find a Joystick Guid
foreach (var deviceInstance in directInput.GetDevices(DeviceType.Gamepad, DeviceEnumerationFlags.AllDevices))
guid = deviceInstance.InstanceGuid;
//create joystick
if (guid!=Guid.Empty)
    controller = new Joystick(directInput, guid);
```

The problem is that controller remains null, which means that the guid remains empty,  which means that the GetDevices method doesn't find a gamepad. Which is strange because the controller is perfectly working in windows 7 and visible in device manager as HID and as Microsoft common controller for windows class.

btw, I got the same problem using Microsoft.DirectX.directInput.

Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to change the DeviceType.Gamepad to DeviceType.Joystick

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why it didn't work. But I tried something better. with a tutorial on youtube i installed a driver which "converted" the DS3 controller into an xbox controller. In other words, windows now thinks there is a xbox controller connected.

Now I can use the GamePad class of the xna library which is designed for xbox 360 controllers.

http://steamcommunity.com/app/258970/discussions/0/613937306592303709/?l=dutch read the comments of this link for more updated drivers.